# Async Loop seems to partially parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I'm trying to implement a function, which slices a file into chunks and then sends them to my backend one after another.

The function has to hash each file & validate if the hash is already known before starting the upload.
The following code is the code part, where my problematic function is called.

```js
        process: async (
          fieldName,
          file,
          metadata,
          load,
          error,
          progress,
          abort,
          transfer,
          options,
        ) => {
          // fieldName is the name of the input field - No direct relevance for us
          // logger.log(`fieldName: ${fieldName}`);

          // Usually Empty - Can be added with Metadata-Plugin
          // logger.log(metadata);

          const source = this.$axios.CancelToken.source();

          const abortProcess = () => {
            // This function is entered if the user has tapped the cancel button
            source.cancel('Operation cancelled by user');

            // Let FilePond know the request has been cancelled
            abort();
          };

          let chunks = [];

          const {
            chunkForce,
            chunkRetryDelays,
            chunkServer,
            chunkSize,
            chunkTransferId,
            chunkUploads,
          } = options;

          // Needed Parameters of file
          const { name, size } = file;

          if (chunkTransferId) {
            /** Here we handle what happens, when Retry-Button is pressed */
            logger.log(`Already defined: ${chunkTransferId}`);
            return { abortProcess };
          }

          this.hashFile(file)
            .then((hash) => {
              logger.log(`File Hashed: ${hash}`);
              if (hash.length === 0) {
                error('Hash not computable');
              }
              return hash;
            })
            .then((hash) => {
              logger.log(`Hash passed through: ${hash}`);
              return this.requestTransferId(file, hash, source.token)
                .then((transferId) => {
                  logger.log(`T-ID receieved: ${transferId}`);
                  return transferId;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  error(err);
                });
            })
            .then((transferId) => {
              transfer(transferId);
              logger.log(`T-ID passed through: ${transferId}`);

              // Split File into Chunks to prepare Upload
              chunks = this.splitIntoChunks(file, chunkSize);

              // Filter Chunks - Remove all those which have already been uploaded with success
              const filteredChunks = chunks.filter(
                (chunk) => chunk.status !== ChunkStatus.COMPLETE,
              );

              logger.log(filteredChunks);

              return this.uploadChunks(
                filteredChunks,
                { name, size, transferId },
                progress,
                error,
                source.token,
              ).then(() => transferId);
            })
            .then((transferId) => {
              // Now Everything should be uploaded -> Set Progress to 100% and make item appear finished
              progress(true, size, size);
              load(transferId);
              logger.log(transferId);
            })
            .catch((err) => error(err));

          return { abortProcess };
        },
```

`uploadChunks` is where the problem starts.

```js
    async uploadChunks(chunks, options, progress, error, cancelToken) {
      const { name, size, transferId } = options;
      for (let index = 0; index < chunks.length; index += 1) {
        let offset = 0;
        const chunk = chunks[index];
        chunk.status = ChunkStatus.PROCESSING;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        await this.uploadChunk(chunk.chunk, options, offset)
          .then(() => {
            chunk.status = ChunkStatus.COMPLETE;
            offset += chunk.chunk.size;
            progress(true, offset, size);
            logger.log(offset); // This is always chunk.chunk.size, instead of getting bigger
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            chunk.status = ChunkStatus.ERROR;
            error(err);
          });
      }
    },
    uploadChunk(fileChunk, options, offset) {
      const { name, size, transferId } = options;
      const apiURL = `${this.$config.api_url}/filepond/patch?id=${transferId}`;
      return this.$axios.$patch(apiURL, fileChunk, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/offset+octet-stream',
          'upload-name': name,
          'upload-length': size,
          'upload-offset': offset,
        },
      });
    },
```

As you can see `uploadChunks` takes an array of chunks, some options, two functions (progress & error) and a cancelToken (which I currently don't use, since I'm still stuck at this problem)

Each chunk in the array has the form of:

```js
{
  status: 0, // Some Status indicating, if it's completed or not
  chunk: // binary data
}
```

The Function `uploadChunks` iterates over the chunk array and should in theory upload one chunk after another and always increment `offset` after each upload and then call `progress`. After this it should start the next iteration of the loop, where `offset` would be bigger than in the call before.

The calls themselves get executed one after another, but every call has the same `offset` and `progress` does not get repeatedly called. Instead my progress-bar locks until everything is uploaded and them jumps to `100%`, due to the `load`-call in the first function right at the end.

So the upload itself works fine in the correct order, but all the code after the `await this.uploadChunk...` doesn't get called after each chunk and blocks somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `offset` to 0 inside the loop. So offset is always 0. You should move this line:

`let offset = 0;`

before the `for` statement.